# Jackson XML sort array by entry's attribute

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xml-parsing, jackson-databind

I have a model Attribute, which in XML is an entry (<Long>, <String>, etc.) inside  an <Attributes/> tag:

```xml
<Attributes>
  <Long position="1"/>
  <String position="0"/>
  <String position="2"/>
</Attributes>
```

The model itself looks like this:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Attribute {

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String name;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String label;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private Integer position;
}
```

And for the array:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JacksonXmlRootElement
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class AttributeWrapper {

  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "String")
  private List<StringAttribute> stringAttributes;

  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Long")
  private List<LongAttribute> longAttributes;

  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Double")
  private List<DoubleAttribute> doubleAttributes;

  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Date")
  private List<DateAttribute> dateAttributes;

  // constructor and setters for lists
}
```

I want entries inside <Attributes/> array to be ordered based on the "position" attribute of a tag, how do I achieve that using Jackson XML?